# Push notification is not working after update of iOS 7.1

Tags: objective-c, ios7

My push notification was working fine before iOS 7.1 update version. It's calling bellow app-delegate method

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
  NSString *strToken=[deviceToken description];
  strToken=[strToken stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
  strToken=[strToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
  strGlobalDeviceToken=strToken;
}
```

but bellow AppDelegate methods are not calling..

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{

  if([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState==UIApplicationStateActive )
  {
     UIAlertView *alertv=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"] delegate:self  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"View", nil];
    [alertv show];
  }
  else
  {
    [self remoteNotification];
  }

}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
   NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
}
```

I am not getting what is wrong with my code..I google for this and i did changes as per answers but still not working.Please help me to solve this issue..On android phone we are getting push notifications but it's not calling on iOS only..

Comment: Check the logs on the server side. That should tell you if the push occurred successfully.

Comment: make sure that your application is listed under "include" section in notification centre

Comment: @Anil I checked server side logs..No issues are there..It's sending notifications on server without any error massage..

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if you ANPS certificate might have expired? I ran into that recently as well, renewing the certificate helps.

Comment: I checked for APNS certificate..it's valid and push notifications are properly sending from our server to apple server without any error but i am not getting why my methods are not calling..